# Add dynamically value in array Angular 2

Tags: arrays, algorithm

How can I add values in array dynamically, I tried like this:

```
this.socios.forEach((data) => {
            this.fieldsSocios = [ 
        new ArraySocios(data.nome, data.participacao)

  ];
```

but, in fieldsSocios has only the last value that was add.
Actually should be 3 objects inside the fieldSocios.

Comment: "How can I add values in array dynamically" this has nothing to do with angular2 nor typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing array in every iteration the `this.fieldsSocios` should be initialized before the loop started.

```
this.fieldsSocios = [];
this.socios.forEach((data) => {
 this.fieldsSocios.push(new ArraySocios(data.nome, data.participacao));
});
```